# Approximating erf by tanh

Tags: real-analysis, approximation-theory, na.numerical-analysis

It appears to be well-known that $\tanh(x)\le \mathrm{erf}(x)$ on $[0,\infty)$. It's off-handedly mentioned [here](http://web.cs.dal.ca/~jborwein/tanh-sinh.pdf), for example. Where can I find a formal proof? On the one hand, it's hard to imagine that a "classic" like this wouldn't have been proven already. On the other hand, the Taylor expansions are somewhat involved (tanh involves Bernoulli numbers) and unfortunately, the inequality does not hold termwise in the expansions -- so it's certainly far from obvious.

Comment: Not an answer but related: http://www.mathapps.net/Holmes/Holmes.pdf

Comment: Tastes vary, but this strikes me as a nice example of a fact for which I would much prefer an informal proof to a formal one. It's obvious from the definitions of the two functions that the inequality must hold for large x. Graphing would establish it for small x.

Comment: If proofs by plotting were sufficient, it would have saved us a lot of work [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3198145/k-s.pdf)...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let $f(x)={\mathrm{erf}}(x)-\tanh(x)$. It can be easily seen from Taylor series
at $0$ and from asymptotics at $\infty$ that $f(x)>0$ for small $x$ and
for large $x$.

Let us prove that $f(x)>0$ by contradiction.
Suppose that $f(x)$ is negative for some $x$, then $f'$ must have
at least $3$ positive zeros, by Rolle's theorem. This means that the equation
$$g(x):=e^{-x^2}(e^{2x}+2+e^{-2x})=2\sqrt{\pi}$$
has at least $3$ positive solutions. But this is not the case because
the LHS is monotone. Indeed, differentiating $g$, dividing by $e^{-x^2}$
and replacing $2x$ with $y$ we obtain
$$g'(x)=\sinh(y)-y\cosh(y)-y<0,$$
because $\sinh(y)  < y \cosh(y)$ as you can see from their Taylor series.

Comment: Sorry, I can only see that, on your supposition, $f'$ has $2$ (or more) positive zeros. But anyway that's enough for the rest of the argument to work. 

Comment: John, if you have a function that tends to zero from the positive
side on
both ends of the interval then derivative has ODD number of zeros.
Only one if it positive everywhere, and at least 3 if not. 

Comment: Yes. But the function $f$ here doesn't tend to zero at *both* ends of the interval $[0, \infty)$, because $f(0)=\mathrm{erf}\, 0-\mathrm{tanh}\,0=\frac{1}{2}-0=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Depends how you define erf. If you take the definition given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), which appears to be standard, then erf(0)=0.

Comment: Thanks, Aryeh. I was confusing erf with a cumulative distribution function.

Answer (score 5):

First,
$$\begin{align}
1-\mathrm{erf}(x) &= \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_x^\infty e^{-t^2}dt,
\cr
1-\tanh(x) &= \int_x^\infty \mathrm{sech}^2 t\;dt .
\end{align}$$
Subtract:
$$
\mathrm{erf}(x)-\mathrm{tanh}(x) = 
\int_x^\infty \left(\mathrm{sech}^2 t - \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-t^2}\right)dt
$$
So it suffices to show that this integrand is positive.  It is positive for $t>1$ (proof needed), so we establish $\mathrm{erf}(x) > \mathrm{tanh}(x)$ for $x > 1$.